# Importing Blog posts from Drupal into Craft

Tags: import

I am using InstaBlog plugin to manage Blogs in Craft. I would like to import some 1000 blog entries from Drupal. I know it has an option to import blogs from WordPress. I was wondering if this can be done from Drupal?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

There are several import plugins that can help you import your data from Drupal, but they may require a bit more configuration than the InstaBlog plugin that is designed for a specific use case.

### Import Plugins

Import plugins like [FeedMe](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) and [Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) provide you a user interface where you can map fields from your import file to fields in Craft. Assuming you can export your data into one of the supported formats for those plugins, you could map the fields from your export and use the interface to import your data.

[Sprout Import](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import) is also a versatile import plugin, but does not currently have a UI. It requires that you get your data into an import-friendly JSON format, and also gives you a lot of flexibility in how you resolve relationships or handle custom data types.

[Drupal Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) is a good plugin to help output your Drupal data in the format that can be used by one of the above import plugins.

### Extract, Transform, Load

A good process to follow as you migrate your data is referred to as the ETL Process (Extract, Transform, Load). You need to:

1. **Extract** - Get your data out of the previous system (in your case Drupal)
2. **Transform** - Transform that data into a format that can be imported into the new system (this can be done with Drupal Views Data Export module, or some other method that can help transform the data in the Drupal Database to importable files for one of the Craft import plugins)
3. **Load** - Import your data into Craft (this step is handled by the Craft import plugins)

For large amounts of data, you'll likely run into several other challenges as well. Many of those questions will likely be documented by the specific import plugin you choose. When working with large migrations, while many things can be handled programmatically, don't forget to consider what can be handled manually as well. Often, a few parts of a migration are easier to do manually and being open to a bit of manual work can help make some of the programmatic steps less complicated.

Answer (score 3):

you might have more luck using the [FeedMe](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin as it can accept an xml file where you can map the fields to fields on your entries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to find out how to map the fields in the xml file to fields in craft cms? Do I match it with the handle name? I know that the fields need to be the same for it to accept any data, but I am not really sure how to match it. Any example would help too. 
Thanks again!

Comment: The feedme plugin should give you an example as to what it will match, if you're still struggling with this, I think it will be best to seek support with them directly... Either trough here or trough their website.